# How to target a particular tab (page) in my goggle worksheet

Tags: tabs, export, google-calendar-api, target

I have a google worksheet with multiple sheets, what do I add to this script to target a particular sheet in that worksheet only? At the moment it's just going to the far left-hand sheet. I've tried "getSheetByName("Calendar")", but I get errors so obviously there is more I need to do.

```
function export_gcal_to_gsheet() {
    var mycal = "email";
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
    var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("July 01, 2022 00:00:00 UTC"), new Date ());
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.clearContents();  
    var header = [["Calendar Address", "Event Title", "Event Description", "Event Location", "Event Start", "Event End", "Calculated Duration", "Visibility", "Date Created", "Last Updated", "MyStatus", "Created By", "All Day Event", "Recurring Event"]]
    var range = sheet.getRange(6, 1, 1, 14);
    range.setValues(header);
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var row = events.length + 6 - i;
        var myformula_placeholder = '';
        var details=[[mycal,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), myformula_placeholder, ('' + events[i].getVisibility()), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated(), events[i].getMyStatus(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].isAllDayEvent(), events[i].isRecurringEvent()]];
        var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,14);
        range.setValues(details);
        var cell=sheet.getRange(row,7);
        cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(F' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(F' +row+ ')/60))-(HOUR(E' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(E' +row+ ')/60))');
        cell.setNumberFormat('.00');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Calendar");` ?

Comment: If that did not work, can you share with us the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use the function getActiveSpreadsheet() before using getSheetByName()

I have tried your script on my side and changed:

`var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();`

to:

`var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Calendar");`

and your script worked fine and populated the desired sheet with the data provided by the script. I assumed you forgot to use the `getActiveSpreadsheet()` function which resulted in your script returning an error.

### Reference

- [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)

Comment: If this does not fix your issue, kindly provide more details (i.e. error message). Feel free to ask if you have other questions related to this issue.